# Can anyone say me how much byte this data type has?

Tags: c, arrays, char, initialization, c-strings

i have here a homework that want to know how much bytes this array has:

char test[]="test";

I know that the data type char has 1 Byte. But how much byte is here?

is it maybe the same?

Thank you all!

Comment: There is a C operator to tell you exactly - `sizeof`.

Answer (score 2):

The array is initialized by the elements of the string literal

```
char test[]="test";
```

So the array has as many elements as the string literal has because the size of the array is not specified explicitly.

The string literal in memory is represented as a character array

```
char literal[] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't', '\0' };
```

That is it has 5 characters including the terminating zero character. All these characters are used to initialize the array.

So the size of the array is equal to `5 * sizeof( char )`. `sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1`. So the size of the array is equal to `5`.

You can check this by calling the standard C function printf

```
printf( "sizeof( test ) = %zu\n", sizeof( test ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char test1[] = "test";

    printf( "sizeof( test1 ) = %zu\n", sizeof( test1 ) );

    char test2[] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't', '\0' };

    printf( "sizeof( test2 ) = %zu\n", sizeof( test2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( test1 ) = 5
sizeof( test2 ) = 5
```

Comment: oh my gosh. Thank you so much! it worked. I didnt now that there is a function which can tell me how much bytes there is. Thanks!

Comment: @majack It is not a function. It is an operator that returns the size of an array.  You could write for example sizeof test1 instead of sizeof( test1 ). Take into account that an array can be greater than a string that it contains. In this case to determine the size of the stored string you have to use standard C function strlen.